# Adding column to customer grid in Magento - Data not populating

Tags: php, magento, datagrid

Trying to add a column with a custom attribute to the admin customer grid in Magento v1.11

I've got this module set up like so:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WACI_AdminHtmlExt>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </WACI_AdminHtmlExt>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>WACI_AdminHtmlExt_Block_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**WACI/AdminHtmlExt/Block/Customer/Grid.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Adminhtml customer grid block
 *
 * @category   WACI
 * @package    WACI_AdminhtmlExt
 * @author     
 */

class WACI_AdminHtmlExt_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'      => 'number',
        ));

       $this->addColumn('customer_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Dynamics ID'),
            'width'     => '75px',
            'index'     => 'customer_id',
        ));

        //... rest of the function, removing a couple columns...


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**Customer_Id**, in this case is a custom attribute (tracking an internal customer id)... Not sure if I need to add logic to render this correctly? But its showing up in the admin just fine, otherwise.

I've read a couple articles that mention adding a renderer for new fields in grids like this - but just as many don't mention it at all.

Not quite sure where to go from here -

Cheers

---

#### update

Just to clarify for those needing this solution:

```
class WACI_AdminHtmlExt_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{

    /*protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                ->addNameToSelect()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }*/

    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id');                    
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('customer_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Dynamics ID'),
            'width'     => '75px',
            'index'     => 'customer_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumnsOrder('customer_id','entity_id');

        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->removeColumn('billing_country_id');


        return $this;
    }
}
```

Is a what I finally landed up. Skipped the `_prepareCollenctions()` call.

Cheers

Comment: Look at this path: WACI/AdminHtmlExt/Block/Customer/Grid.php ... I suggest you to try to rename AdminHtmlExt to AdminhtmlExt. Please share the result.

Comment: /facepalm. yeah. that was it exactly.
Ok - getting a column now - but no data...

Comment: @Bosworth99 do you mean, that my suggestion worked for you?

Comment: thats definitely where the fatal error was coming from - but Its just revealed a deeper issue with the logic, now that its functioning. See my update.

Comment: @Bosworth99 This is really cool, but why you don't open a new question then? You question title is: "Non-Object Fatal Error when adding column to customer grid in Magento" Many people will land here from some search engine and this will not make sense for them.

Comment: Agreed - actually - I'm just going to update the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your return statement calling parent::_prepareCollection() combined with the fact you are extending the original class. By calling the parent class after your class you are replacing the collection object you created with the original. What you actually need to call is the parent of the class your overloading, which you can do like so...

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: Ah! your're completely right. That makes a ton of sense... Cheers

Comment: You could have also solved it by calling parent::_prepareCollection before your code, then return $this, but in this instance, there's no reason to call the code in the parent, since you actually want to replace all of it.

Comment: Yeah.. messing around further with this - amended _prepareColumns() much like that. I hate dumping the whole contents of a method into an override...  (see update)

Comment: Just a heads up, you shouldn't need the call to sortColumnsByOrder, it'll get called during the call to parent::_prepareColumns. Also, there is an addColumnAfter function that combines addColumn and addColumnsOrder. No big deal, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: So there is. The scavenger hunt continues... thanks for the help!

Comment: I like overriding function setCollection better than _prepareCollection as calling grand parent is a bit weird concept (though Magento's core ever use it too)

Comment: I don't necessarily think it's a weird concept, the objective is to replace the function on the original class, if this was javascript, you'd actually be able to replace it. But in the case of PHP you can't just replace the function, you have to extend the class. Interesting suggestion to override setCollection however, I quite like the idea, that way if new columns are added by core you'd still likely get them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mis-0read code block because of line break when I first answered.

It seems that your `createBlock()` method is not returning a valid object.

Comment: yeah = check out my update - stupid mistake on my part. Seems to be a problem with the logic at this point, tho.