# Sort order on custom column from customer grid

Tags: magento, collections, grid, magento-1.5

On my Admin side customer grid, i have a situacion, some times and some customers on column name i need First Name + Last Name, it's already done by magento core, but some customer i need just to print First name. Take a look on my Grid.php, i need take off last name from 'name' catenation, but when i remove from collection my column sort stop work.

```
<?php

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    /*foreach($collection as $customer){
        preg_match("/[A-z| ]*//*", $customer->getName(), $name);
        $customer->setName($name[0]);
        unset($name);
    }*/

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));

    /*
    $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));
    */

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'email'
    ));

    $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('group', array(
        'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
        'width'     =>  '100',
        'index'     =>  'group_id',
        'type'      =>  'options',
        'options'   =>  $groups,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ZIP'),
        'width'     => '90',
        'index'     => 'billing_postcode',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Country'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'type'      => 'country',
        'index'     => 'billing_country_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('State/Province'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'index'     => 'billing_region',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_since', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Since'),
        'type'      => 'datetime',
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'created_at',
        'gmtoffset' => true
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Website'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'width'     => '80px',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
            'index'     => 'website_id',
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('customer');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
         'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete'),
         'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
         'confirm'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_subscribe', array(
         'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Subscribe to Newsletter'),
         'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSubscribe')
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_unsubscribe', array(
         'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Unsubscribe from Newsletter'),
         'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massUnsubscribe')
    ));

    $groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();

    array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('assign_group', array(
         'label'        => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Assign a Customer Group'),
         'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
         'additional'   => array(
            'visibility'    => array(
                 'name'     => 'group',
                 'type'     => 'select',
                 'class'    => 'required-entry',
                 'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
                 'values'   => $groups
             )
        )
    ));

    return $this;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
}
```

}

Its wrong way i know, but have to get just first name and don't have other way. 
But now this make my sort on columns from grid stop work. I need sort working. 
If i remove this 3 lines from my _prepareCollection(), it's work fine but i need it too and with it don't work my sort. I'm crazy with this someone can help???

Ty in advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best bet would be to load the firstname attribute on the collection and add that as an independent column. [Adding column to customer grid in Magento - Data not populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411795/adding-column-to-customer-grid-in-magento-data-not-populating) will give you a good start. You should just need to add in `->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')` and then add the column in the prepareColumns function...

```
$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
    'index'     => 'firstname'
));
```

Comment: ty for your attention, but my case if different i have one kind of customer that don't have to show the last name, but some kind of customer i need the First Name + Last Name. I'm using one column 'name' and it working well, and do the sort. But, if i look on this collection for the last name what i don't want to show and change it stop work sort on grid. How i tell to grid how do the sort and what field should use? Take a look on my Grid.php:

Comment: I fail to see why you are trying to shoehorn two different functionalities into a single column. Having two columns would allow you to sort what you want. If you really want a single column your best bet would probably be to create a new attribute for special_name, and then update this value on a customer _before_save event to be whatever is right for that type of customer.

Comment: I see, so this way i'm trying to do never gonna work? What you are saying make sense. But is kindda of out of way make this on that project. But i'll think about it. Ty

Comment: The problem is that, by post processing with PHP to change the value, you can't use the in-built sort / search functionality of the grid. Since this is operating at a database level.

Comment: i imaginate is that what's happen. so i think i should find other way. ty so mutch @Cags